# Catching exceptions from complex chains of tasks

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a .Net core app that basically does something like this:

```
public async Task<IOBoundStuffResult> DoIOBoundStuff()
{
    // Do IO bound stuff ...
    
    return new IOBoundStuffResult
    {
        Id = getIdForThing()
    };
}

public async Task<OtherIOBoundStuffResult> DoOtherIOBoundStuff()
{
    // Do other IO bound stuff ...
    
    return new OtherIOBoundStuffResult
    {
        Uri = getUriForThing()
    };
}

public async Task<IOBoundTaskResult> DoIOBoundStuff()
{
    var ioBoundTask1 = doIOBoundStuff();
    var ioBoundTask2 = doOtherIOBoundStuff();
    
    return await Task.WhenAll(ioBoundTask1, ioBoundTask2)
        .ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
            var id = ioBoundTask1.Result.Id;
            var uri = ioBoundTask2.Result.Uri;
            
            doSomethingWithIdAndUri(id, uri);
            
            return new IOBoundTaskResult
            {
                Id = id,
                Uri = uri
            };
        });
}

public async Task<IActionResult> DoThing()
{
    try
    {
        var cpuBoundTask = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            doCPUBoundStuff();
        });
        
        var ioBoundTask = DoIOBoundStuff();
        
        // do stuff with ioBoundTask, cpuBoundTask
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        // Process System.Exception.AggregateException, other exceptions
    }
}
```

The problem here is that if something in one of those tasks throws an exception (in particular `doSomethingWithIdAndUri()`) then the exception is not caught by the try...catch block and results in a crash. I've tried creating continuation tasks with `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted` to handle exceptions, but all that seems to do is always cause a `TaskCancelledException` to be thrown. How can I catch exceptions that are thrown from tasks?

Comment: Await them? [Adding characters to meet requirements]

Comment: @PeterBons Yes, I am awaiting cpuBoundTask, ioBoundTask, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I see a Task.Run that doesn't seem to be awaited, is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for a task's exception to "bubble up", it has to be awaited. If, when awaited, an exception has been thrown, that exception will be re-thrown in the current context (though it may sometimes be wrapped in another exception type, such as an `AggregateException`.

You need to either change, for example, `var ioBoundTask = DoIOBoundStuff();` to `var ioBoundTask = await DoIOBoundStuff();`, or catch the exceptions elsewhere by awaiting the tasks and wrapping the awaits in another try-catch block.

Take care to await **every single async method**. Avoid using `async void` as you can't await them. Instead, use `async Task`.

EDITED to add:
Your use of `ContinueWith` is seems a little peculiar in an async context. Rather than

```cs
return await Task.WhenAll(ioBoundTask1, ioBoundTask2)
        .ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
            var id = ioBoundTask1.Result.Id;
            var uri = ioBoundTask2.Result.Uri;
            
            doSomethingWithIdAndUri(id, uri);
            
            return new IOBoundTaskResult
            {
                Id = id,
                Uri = uri
            };
        });
```

You could write something like

```cs
var result1 = await ioBoundTask1;
var result2 = await ioBoundTask2;

var id = result1.Id;
var uri = result2.Uri;
            
doSomethingWithIdAndUri(id, uri);
            
return new IOBoundTaskResult
{
    Id = id,
    Uri = uri
};
```

This makes it clearer what's happening, and makes it easier to avoid issues like exceptions being thrown in the wrong place / not at all. There are situations when more explicit use of continuations is required, but in general it should be avoided in favour of cleaner, more succinct async/await syntax.

EDIT: [Here's a link to my version of the code](https://gist.github.com/Humandoodlebug/714a6a2db8e6ed1934758442bf70c217), where the exception should "bubble up" correctly.

Comment: Yep, the problem was that doSomethingWithIdAndUri was async void.  Changing that and awaiting it fixed this.  Thanks.